# Understanding OOP in Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

```
A.as : 

    public class A {

    public function getFunction():Function { 
      return function():void {
        if(this is C) {
          trace("C");
        } else {
          trace("not C");
        }
     }
  }


public function func1():void {
   var internalFunc:Function = getFunction();
   internalFunc();
 }

}

B.as : 
public class B extends A implements C {

}
```

In some other class :

```
var b:B = new B();
   B.func1();
```

Output is : 
   "Not C"

I was expecting the trace output to be
    "C"

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [anonymous function](http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2004/08/anonymous-inline-and-named-functions-in-actionscript.cfm), if called directly, is scoped to the *global object*. If you trace `this` inside it, you will see `[object global]` instead of `[object B]`, as you would, if this refered to `b`.

A common workaround is using a closure:

```
  var self:A = this;
  return function():void {
    if(self is C) {
      trace("C");
    } else {
      trace("not C");
    }
 }
```

Please note however, the instance-members of a class defining an anonymous function are available from within. This works, because they are resolved at compile time.

**edit** in response to Amarghosh's question:

Yes, `this` points to the global object, but that doesn't mean, you cannot access the instance members of the declaring class. This little piece of code should explain the details:

```
package  {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 public class Test extends Sprite {
  private var foo:String = "foo";
  public function Test() {
   var anonymous:Function = function ():void {
    trace(foo);//foo
    trace(this.foo);//undefined
   };
   anonymous();
  } 
 }
}
```

greetz
back2dos

Comment: His code sample doesn't have an anonymous function, though.  Here is a good write up on anonymous functions in Flex: 
http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2004/08/anonymous-inline-and-named-functions-in-actionscript.cfm

Comment: instance members will be available only if you assign `this`  to a local variable within the enclosing function, right? Otherwise with `this` pointing to global, what would you use to refer to them?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com : See Amarghosh's comment to your response.

Comment: I saw it; I must have done a bad copy and paste job when I tried to run his code.

Comment: So the behavior for anonymous functions is weird since it is scoped to Global but can access instance members?

Answer (score 1):

A few things with the code that I assume are just typos?

The getFunction() method doesn't return anything and will thus cause a compiler error.
Your call code calls func1() as a static method, not as a method on an instance of the B.  This will also cause a compiler error.  I believe these are typos.

In my tests, using your modified code.  The output is C.  There must be something else going on with your code.  Here are my mods to A:

```
    public function getFunction():Function { 
        if(this is C) {
            trace("C");
        } else {
            trace("not C");
        }
        return getFunction;
    }
```

Here is my mod to the runnable code, which I put in creationComplete of an empty MXML Application file:

```
            var b:B = new B();
            b.func1();
```

I assume your "real world" code is more extensive than the sample and there must be something else going on.

Comment: He is returning an anonymous function from `getFunction` and calling it from `func1` - `this` will be `global` as suggested by back2dos

Comment: I must have copied and pasted his code incorrectly when I tried to run it; as the getFunction was returning nothing.

Comment: @flextras.com, you did not copy it incorrectly :-). I had edited my code after posting it for the first time..

Comment: @dta,  Thanks for the clarification; good to know I'm that crazy yet. :-)